# How do I implement a Document Provider Extension in Xamarin?

Tags: ios, security, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I maintain a store of encrypted data I would like to expose to other applications.  Right now the data requires a passcode to unlock/decrypt that data.

The document provider extension I created so far doesn't seem to be loading (I checked the certificates) and I can't expose that to the other apps.

Are there any examples of how to do this?

I've already looked at the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_document_picker/), the Git repository of various team members of Xamarin, and all the other general sources.

Are there any special gotcha's I need to address and may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a good start : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16071/encryption-decryption-in-xamarin

And to get a complete working solution. Refer the Kinder Chat app.
https://github.com/xamarin/KinderChat

Hope that helps